# xmlstarlet: How to conditionally add missing element (upsert)

Tags: xmlstarlet

Using XMLStarlet, I want to add another property to the list,

```
<document>
   <properties>
       <property>...</property>
       <property>...</property>  <!-- add this! -->
   </properties>
</document>
```

which would be easy, except that the "properties" tag is optional and may be missing in the original document, in which case the "properties" tag needs to be conditionally created.

Answer (score 3):

The `ed` subcommand doesn't have any conditionals, so there is no nice way, but I think you could insert a new `properties` element and then delete it if turns out to be "extra" (i.e. not the first):

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  -s /document -t elem -n properties -v '' \
  -d '/document/properties[position() != 1]' \
  -s /document/properties -t elem -n property -v 'new property value' \
  doc.xml
```

Otherwise, you could check first with `sel` and use shell conditionals to decide whether insertion is needed.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Batch, You could do a SEL and then check the %errorlevel% 
0 means it was found
1 means it was not found

Example:

```
xmlstarlet.exe -q sel -t -c "/config/option[@name='product']" xml.cfg
if %errorlevel%==1 (
    xmlstarlet.exe ed -L -s "/config/" -t elem -n "option" -v "" -i "/config/option[last()]" -t attr -n "name" -v "product" xml.cfg
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I am using in a batch, you will need sed:

```
rem var may be set by following command
Set NodeCount=

rem count how many nodes, pipe to sed to put in the SET
xml sel -T -t -v "count(/document/properties)" -n doc.xml|sed "s/^/Set NodeCount=/" >tmp2.bat

Call tmp2.bat
Delete tmp2.bat

if "%NodeCount%"=="0" Goto NoNodes

rem Do Insert Node Here

Goto :eof

:NoNodes

rem handle no nodes Here
```

If you find a better way I am all ears.